# use awk to left outer join two csv file based on multiple columns while keeping order of the first file observations

Tags: linux, awk, left-join

I have two csv files.

File 1

```
ID,Name,Gender,Salary,DOB
11,Jim,M,200,90
12,David,M,100,89
12,David,M,300,89
13,Lucy,F,150,86
14,Lily,F,200,85
13,Lucy,F,100,86
```

File 2

```
DOB,Name,Children
90,Jim,2
88,Michael,4
88,Lily,1
85,Lily,0
```

What I want to do is to left outer join File 2 into File 1 based on DOB and Name while keeping the order of File 1 observations. 
So the output is expected to be

```
ID,Name,Gender,Salary,DOB,Children
11,Jim,M,200,90,2
12,David,M,100,89,
12,David,M,300,89,
13,Lucy,F,150,86,
14,Lily,F,200,85,0
13,Lucy,F,100,86,
```

I learned that we need to sort data if we use `join` command. So I was wondering whether I could use `awk` to do my work. But I am new with `awk`. Is there anyone can help me? By the way, if the data is very big, can I drop `print` command in `awk` but simply use `> *.csv` to save into a new csv file? It's because I found solutions to some related questions in this website often used `{print ...}`. Thank you.

Comment: is there ary guarantee that name+dob combination is unique in file 1?  Is the empty space part of the data or you just did it for formatting.  If so, better to post the actual data.  Also, are the headers part of the files?  If so, why not comma separated?  If you post sample files that can be copy pasted to test the script that will be most useful.

Comment: Name+dob does not need to be unique. They can occurs repeatedly. In File 2, it's unique. I have revised my sample. Thank you.

Comment: How big is *very big*?

Comment: Like 2 TB. That's just an assumption. If there are too many observations, print will make all obs filled with your linux window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3; next} {print $0 FS a[$NF,$2]}' file2 file1

ID,Name,Gender,Salary,DOB,Children
11,Jim,M,200,90,2
12,David,M,100,89,
12,David,M,300,89,
13,Lucy,F,150,86,
14,Lily,F,200,85,0
13,Lucy,F,100,86,
```

`join` will require sorted input and you need embellishments to recover initial ordering.  You can redirect the output to a file by adding `> outputfile.csv`

Comment: Thank you, karakfa. It worked. I have an extended issue. Suppose file 2 has four columns, which are DOB, Name, Children, and Class. I tried to mimic your code, and typed ``` awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3, $4; next} {print $0 FS a[$NF,$2]}' ``` in linux. But it warned a syntax error. How shall I do? Thank you.

Comment: I guess I figured out it my self. I typed "awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3 FS $4; next} {print $0 FS a[$NF,$2]}'".